# How to change the python version in blender

Tags: python, scripting

I'm using Blender 2.71 and it comes with Python 3.4.0 even though the most recent version is 3.4.1. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: What for? Of course you can use a different Python installation or update the Python libs and compile Blender yourself. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules-scipy http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/302/how-to-change-the-python-version-that-blender-uses

Comment: By the way, the most recent version of blender is 2.74.

Comment: Ok. I'm still using 2.73a.