# Blender Win32 error

Tags: error

I am trying to get into scripting for blender but its not opening! I dont know if this has anything to do with the fact that i recently installed pyhton standalone?? i checked my python version and it is 3.5

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Blender brings a bundled Python installation by default, you shouldn't need any standalone Python package

Comment: Im using a standalone for programming purposes.. is there anything else you can think of that i can do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Blender use Python2.x?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/302/how-to-make-blender-use-python2-x)

Comment: Try reinstalling blender.

Comment: i have installed like 3 different versions and uninstalled all but still nothign